# PHPMailer no errors but no mail received

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

Trying out this PHPMailer. The goal is to email people videos from this interactive photo booth, but I'm starting from the ground up. Not a PHP person. I've spent a couple hours trying to get this to work, reading docs, no luck! It tells me the mail has been sent but it doesn't receive on the other end. I've tried several to/from addresses, made sure I have control of the from address on a given SMTP server. I tried using Googles SMTP and it said my app was too unprotected or something, so I switched to HostMonster who I have an account with, no luck.

What's the deal?

```
<?php
require("/Users/jargon/Desktop/workbench/net/dell/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer();  
$body = "this is the body";   
$mail->IsSMTP();  // telling the class to use SMTP 
$mail->Mailer = "smtp";

$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // turn on SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";     
$mail->Host = "";
$mail->Port = 26;
$mail->Username = ""; // SMTP username
$mail->Password = ""; // SMTP password 

$mail->SetFrom     = "";  

$mail->Subject  = "Dell Powered";  
$mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!";
$mail->MsgHTML($body);

$address = "";
$mail->AddAddress($address, "");

if(!$mail->Send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
}

?>
```

Comment: Did you check SPAM folder?

Comment: Yes I did, nothing there